# Alternating Direction Loop

Tags: python

I am trying to make a snakes and ladders game, and I want to make a grid go left to right then vice versa like a snake, but I'm only able to make it go left to right then reset back to the left like writing text.

```
for i in range(0,100):

    w = WIDTH / 10

    h = HEIGHT / 10

    x = i * w - (i // 10) * WIDTH 

    y = (i // 10) * h

    boardPlaces.append(Rect((x,y),(w,h)))
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to make it more like a traditional snakes and ladder board with a basic loop in python or if I should just brute force it with multiple loop functions.
Grid is 10 by 10 for 100 squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an if condition in the for loop, to detect whether it's on an odd row or even row. If it's on an even row, then x go from left to right (`0*w` to `9*w`); otherwise go from right to left (from `9*w` to `0*w`).

```py
# we can put w and h outside the loop because they're fixed values
w = WIDTH / 10
h = HEIGHT / 10

for i in range(0,100):
    row = i // 10
    if row % 2 == 0:
        # even row: x from 0w, 1w to 9w
        x = i % 10 * w
    else:
        # odd row: x from 9w, 8w to 0w
        x = 9 * w - i % 10 * w

    y = row * h

    boardPlaces.append(Rect((x,y),(w,h)))
```